# Steps to add a cocos2d scene to a UIView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone say the steps to add `cocos2d` scene to a uikit project. I am new to `cocos2d` and not aware how to add the files related to `cocos2d` and also please explain where to add the eagl view in the ui files.

And also share a link for adding a `cocos2d` in a uiview and not the other way round.

Thanks

Comment: My book answers that question. You can freely download the source code with examples if you just need the code, which you can download here (in table at the bottom): http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/

Answer (score 1):

For my mind, it is not a good idea to mix uikit with cocos2d. Examples of creating eaglview you can find in any of cocos2d templates. Here you can read how to install cocos2d templates.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test